# Flattening nested array returns an array with undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create my own flattening array method that goes 1 level deep by using nested loops to push all elements from the array and nested array to a new array. I have no idea why the returned array contains undefined where the nested array was. Any suggestions?

```js
let arr = [1,[2,4],3,2]

function flatten(array) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
    if (Array.isArray(array[x])){
      for (let y = 0; y < array.length; y++){
          newArr.push(array[x][y])
      }
    } else {
      newArr.push(array[x])
    }
  } 
  return newArr
}
console.log(flatten(arr));
//returns [ 1, 2, 4, undefined, undefined, 3, 2 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop up to the inner array's length instead of the length of the entire array.

```
for (let y = 0; y < array[x].length; y++){
```

You can also use the built-in [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) function for this.

```
let result = arr.flat(1);//1 is the depth to flatten the array to
//equivalent to arr.flat()
```

You can easily completely flatten an array like so:

```
let result = arr.flat(Infinity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in Array.prototype.flat() function.

`[1,2,[3,4]].flat()` returns `[1,2,3,4]`

Answer (score 0):

I've always used

```
[].concat.apply([], multi-dimension-array)
```

I learned this while learning WebGL. It's fast and works in Internet Explorer, while `Array.prototype.flat` isn't supported in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the length of the nested array instead of the original array in the inner function.

```js
let arr = [1,[2,4],3,2]

function flatten(array) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
    if (Array.isArray(array[x])){
      for (let y = 0; y < array[x].length; y++){<-----It shoudl be arr[x]
          newArr.push(array[x][y])
      }
    } else {
      newArr.push(array[x])
    }
  } 
  return newArr
}

console.log(flatten(arr))
```

Additionally you can use `flat`

```js
let arr = [1,[2,4],3,2];

var res = arr.flat();

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in this line `for (let y = 0; y < array.length; y++){` you should loop the length of the nested array change it to `y < array[x].length`

```js
   arr = [1,[2,4],3,2]

  function flatten(array) {
    let newArr = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
      if (Array.isArray(array[x])){
        for (let y = 0; y < array[x].length; y++){
            newArr.push(array[x][y])
        }
      } else {
        newArr.push(array[x])
      }
    } 
    return newArr
  }
  console.log(flatten(arr))
```

alternatively you could simply use `flat()`

```js
 arr = [1,[2,4],3,2] 
 newarr=arr.flat()
 console.log(newarr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reduce:

```
const arr = [1,[2,4],3,2]

const flat = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  return acc.concat(item)
}, [])

console.log(flat)
```